# how to store row value in a variable using describe in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

this is my code

```
$select="describe 2mcom";
 $res = MySQL_query($select);
 while($row = MySQL_fetch_array($res)){
echo $row[Field]."<br>" ;
}
```

this is the output:

- exam_name
- session
- student_type
- course_code
- roll_no
- enrollment_no
- student_name

Now what i want is that i want to store the value like exam_name or session in a variable so that i can print it separately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $select="describe 2mcom";
    $res = mysql_query($select);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
       //echo $row[Field]."<br>" ;
       $$row[Field] = $row[Field];
    }
echo $exam_name;
echo $session;
echo $student_type;
```

I insist you to use mysqli_* functions instead of mysql_* as it is deprecated now.
It should work for you!

Answer (score 0):

Probably easier then you think:

```
$exam_name = $row['exam_name'];
// further down
echo 'The name of this exam is '. $exam_name;
```

Comment: exam_name is field name and 2mcom is the name of the table.. and i want to print the field name not the values stored in field exam_name